# How can I turn 2 queries into one in SQL?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to turn this query into one line/query ?

```
//to get the product_id
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE sku = "a-12AB"

//Then do this after having product_id
SELECT * FROM `shopify_export_product_ids` WHERE product_id = "23467"
```

Comment: How are products and shopify_export_product_ids joined and do you want to have all columns from both tables?

Comment: Had you tried to use `JOIN`?

Comment: Let’s say the answer is unknown. Can we do it ? Do we need to know the relationship?

Comment: I was wondering we can do something similar like bash scripting store a variable contain a dynamic value and use that value on the next query.

Comment: SQL joins do that. They basically tell you, match that value with another value from another table that are logically connected and retrieve given result set. This is the whole point of using RDB, however you need to know the structures, the private and foreign keys on the tables.

Comment: It's an interesting query, so in the second query how you know the product_id if you don't know the relationship or is it an arbitary value?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms used. (The above queries are product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `products` has a column `product_id` and it's a [primary key](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php) there and that `product_id` in `shopify_export_product_ids` is the [foreign key](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php), containing the values form the `products.product_id`, you can join the tables:

```
SELECT shopi.*
  FROM products prd
       INNER JOIN shopify_export_product_ids shopi ON shp.product_id = prd.product_id
 WHERE prd.sku = 'a-12AB'
```

the function of this will be to look up the `product_id` in `products` and match the value corresponding to sku = "a-12AB" and then retrieve the results from `shopify_export_product_ids`, corresponding to that `product_id`.

Comment: This is probably closest to what OP wants. Perhaps a LEFT JOIN should be used, if there's no matching shopify_export_product_ids row.

Comment: You're working!

Answer (score 2):

s bioth tables share productid, you can join them
stil SELECT * is a bad szyle, as you usually you don't need all the coumns

so try to avoid it

```
SELECT sh.*,pr.* FROM `shopify_export_product_ids` sh INNER JOIN 
`products` pr ON sh.product_id= pr.product_id 
WHERE pr.sku = "a-12AB" and sh. product_id = "23467"
```

Comment: sh. and pr. ? pls explain.

Comment: sh ? you're too advance for me :)

Comment: aliases are used to make queries better readable, else you need to write the complete table name and hey are the only way to join the same table

Comment: 1054 - Unknown column 'pr.product_id' in 'on clause', Time: 0.022000s

Comment: replace in the query `sh.product_id= pr.product_id ` with `sh.product_id= pr.id`, as i don't know your table strucure you have to replace the columns with the ones you have for example product has a filed were you have 23467 stored, this could be ìd`or something else. but that column you nee in the on clause

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UNION`, so your code will look like this:

```
(SELECT *
    FROM `products`
    WHERE sku = "a-12AB")
UNION
(SELECT *
    FROM `shopify_export_product_ids`
    WHERE product_id = "23467")
```

**Edit:** like Stu mentionned, the structure of both tables needs to be the same, otherwise your final table will have NULL-values.

Comment: I like the union idea 

Comment: Of course this only works if both tables have identical schema and you know the product_id before looking it up with the first query...

Comment: so I guess I can do that.

Comment: If the structure isn't the same you get an error, not null values

Comment: Well on Oracle Apex it would give NULL-values.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a foreign key that links the two tables, you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM products p, shopify_export_product_ids s WHERE p.sku = "a-12AB" AND s.product_id = "23467" AND s.product_id = p.product_id;
```

Comment: Just a note, you don't need foreign keys to JOIN. (Their main purpose is to enforce data consistency.)

Comment: 1054 - Unknown column 'p.product_id' in 'where clause', Time: 0.018000s

Comment: I don't know product id in advance, I think I can use your command

Comment: Imagine I only know SKU.

Comment: Please don't teach people antiquated, comma separated, join style. `join...on...` Is the standard for 30-odd years, it's easier to write, easier to read and easier to maintain